# Can I forward my own number to a twilio number?

Tags: twilio

I've created a web app (CRM) where my customers can call their contacts from the web app itself, without having to use their phone. Using callerId attribute for outgoing calls, I can make sure the contacts they call see the correct phone number on their call and not some random twilio number they don't recognize.

My problem is doing the same thing for incoming calls. So if a contact calls one of my customers, I want them to be able to handle **incoming** calls in the web app as well, but I guess I need to set up some type of call forwarding or something.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want your customers to conduct all of their voice conversations over Twilio, then your best bet is to get them to [port their number into Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179348-Porting-a-Phone-Number-to-Twilio). That way, Twilio will have control of both inbound and outbound calls.

Otherwise, while the number is still controlled by the original carrier, you would have to setup forwarding on the carrier side to send it into Twilio.

Comment: Ok damn, both of those solutions are pretty impossible to do programatically to give our customers a seamless experience for outgoing AND incoming calls. But I understand the limitations. Thanks.

Comment: The alternative is to setup your customers with Twilio phone numbers in the first place so that al their business dealings are made via the Twilio number, both inbound and outbound.

Comment: Good point but all our customers usually have big company wide mobile phone contracts with national carriers, providing 24/7 company support in that countrys language etc. But definitely worth considering.